# Running a python script in a windows shell multiple times

Tags: python, powershell

I'd like to run the following shell command 10 times

```
./file.py 1111x
```

with the 'x' ranging from 0 to 9

i.e. a different port for each .file.py file. I need each instance running in its own shell. I already tried creating a batch file and a python script that calls the windows shell but both without success.

Answer (score 0):

What about this...

```
import os
import subprocess 
for x in range(0,10):
    command = './file.py 1111'  + str(x)
    os.system(command)
    #or
    subprocess.call('cmd ' + command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Calling Python as a subprocess of Python is kind of crazy. You can probably `import file` and call its `main` function or similar ten times instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a powershell job. You may need to tweak this a bit to accommodate your specific requirements, but this should do what you need.

```
[ScriptBlock]$PyBlock = {
   param (
     [int]$x,
     [string]$pyfile
   )
   try {
     [int]$Port = (11110 + $x)
     python $pyfile $Port
   }
   catch {
     Write-Error $_
   }
}

try {
  0..9 | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job -Name "PyJob $_" -ScriptBlock $PyBlock -ArgumentList @($_, 'path/to/file.py')
  }

  Get-Job | Wait-Job -Timeout <int> 
     #If you do not specify a timeout then it will wait indefinitely. 
     #If you use -Timeout then make sure it's long enough to accommodate the runtime of your script. 

  Get-Job | Receive-Job
}
catch {
  throw $_
}
```